# How to prove the commutativity of the iterated integral? A detail in the proof of Cartan Identity in nevanlinna's theory.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fubini-tonelli-theorems

My quetion is just a small detail about the commutability of a iterated integral in the proof, one can omit the unrelated things and go to where I'm confused. 
Let f be a meromorphic function defined on the disc $B(O,R)$, $O$ is not a zero, $r<R$, there are some functions discussed in the identity.
$$log^{+}(a)=\max\{0,log(a)\}$$
$$T_f（r）=m_f(r)+N_f(r) \\m_f(r)=\int_0^{2\pi} log|re^{i\theta}|d\theta \\N_f(r)=\sum_{a\,f(a)=\infty}ord_f(a)log(\frac{r}{|a|})$$
we want to prove the cartan's identity.
$$T_f（r）=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}{N_f(re^{i\theta})d\theta}+log^{+}|f(0)|$$
In order to keep the completeness, i'd like to reiterate the proof. By using Jenson's formula to $f(z)-e^{i\theta}$ on the circle $B(O,r)$, we get
$$log|f(0)-e^{i\theta}|=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}log|f(re^{i\phi})-e^{i\theta}|d\phi+N_f(r)$$
Then we integrate $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$.
$$\int_0^{2\pi}log|f(0)-e^{i\theta}|d\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}d\theta\int_0^{2\pi}log|f(re^{i\phi})-e^{i\theta}|d\phi+2\pi N_f(r)$$After we commute the order, and notice that$$\log^+|a|=\int_0^{2\pi}log|a-e^{i\theta}|d\theta$$, we can get the identity we want.
Now my question is, how to prove the iterated intergral can commute. I'm trying to prove the integrability of $|log|f(re^{i\phi}-e^{i\theta}||$, and then fubini's theory can be used, but I have no idea with the absolute value of this function, which may have a lot of poles.
Any help is appreciated.